# APC OpCode - apc.filters - Excluding a directory from cache

Tags: apc

I have recently implemented APC on my KnownHost SSD VPS and it is working very well (WordPress sites).

One thing I would like to do is exclude a directory (or directories) from the cache. 
I have read the documentation on apc.filters, and it seems confusing to me on whether directories or just file types can be excluded. I have also done extensive searching on the web, and have not found a working example of excluding a directory. 
I have tried numerous variations for apc.filters, and have yet to find one that will exclude my directory.

So if my directory is located on this path in the server:

/home/my_user/public_html/my_directory

**What would the correct value be for apc.filters to exclude the "my_directory" sub-directory?**

Answer (score 0):

*Moved from the question*

**UPDATE: I found the answer (with help from KnownHost)**

The correct syntax to exclude one directory is:

```
apc.filters = "-my_directory/.*";
```

Multiple directories are:

```
apc.filters = "-my_directory/.*,-my_directory2/.*";
```

I hope this can help someone out there, as I could not get it right, or find any information on it.

Thanks

In the interest of complete information, here are my APC runtime settings:

```
apc.cache_by_default    1
apc.canonicalize    1
apc.coredump_unmap  0
apc.enable_cli  0
apc.enabled 1
apc.file_md5    0
apc.file_update_protection  2
apc.filters 
apc.gc_ttl  3600
apc.include_once_override   0
apc.lazy_classes    0
apc.lazy_functions  0
apc.max_file_size   2M
apc.mmap_file_mask  /tmp/apc.XXXXXX
apc.num_files_hint  3000
apc.preload_path    
apc.report_autofilter   0
apc.rfc1867 0
apc.rfc1867_freq    0
apc.rfc1867_name    APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix  upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl 3600
apc.serializer  default
apc.shm_segments    1
apc.shm_size    512M
apc.slam_defense    0
apc.stat    1
apc.stat_ctime  0
apc.ttl 7200
apc.use_request_time    1
apc.user_entries_hint   4096
apc.user_ttl    7200
apc.write_lock  1
```

---

Comments from other users suggest that it may also be necessary to set `apc.cache_by_default=0`